# Move separator elements upwards in xml hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt, hierarchy, separator

I have an xml document with separators deep down in the hierarchy.

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C id='1'/>
    <separator/>
    <C id='2'/>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C id='3'/>
    <separator/>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C id='4'/>
  </B>
</A>
```

I want to move the separators upwards, keeping elements in order. So the desired output is

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C id='1'/>
  </B>
</A>
<separator/>
<A>
  <B>
    <C id='2'/>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C id='3'/>
  </B>
</A>
<separator/>
<A>
  <B>
    <C id='4'/>
  </B>
</A>
```

How can it be done using xslt 1.0 only? Can it be done without `for-each`, using template match only?

UPDATE:
I actually got 4 brilliant answers of different levels of generality, thank you, guys.

Comment: Excellent question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: +1 I enjoyed answering this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kCByFollSep" match="C"
             use="generate-id(following::separator[1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="A">
        <xsl:for-each select="B/separator|B[last()]/*[last()]">
            <A>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                     select="key('kCByFollSep',
                                 substring(generate-id(),
                                           1 div boolean(self::separator)))"/>
            </A>
            <xsl:copy-of select="self::separator"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="C">
        <B>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </B>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C id="1" />
    </B>
</A>
<separator />
<A>
    <B>
        <C id="2" />
    </B>
    <B>
        <C id="3" />
    </B>
</A>
<separator />
<A>
    <B>
        <C id="4" />
    </B>
</A>
```

**Note**: Grouping by following `separator`, adding last third level element for posible `C` without following `separator`.

**Edit**: More pull style, more schema agnostic, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kCByFollSep" match="C"
             use="generate-id(following::separator[1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="separator|*[not(*)][not(following::*)]">
        <A>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                     select="key('kCByFollSep',
                                 substring(generate-id(),
                                           1 div boolean(self::separator)))"
                     mode="output"/>
        </A>
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::separator"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="C" mode="output">
        <B>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </B>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT 2**: More general solution (one thing I do not trust, ja!)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:param name="pRemains"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::node()
                                                   [not(self::separator)]
                                                   [count(following::separator)
                                                    = $pRemains]
                                               ][1]|@*">
                <xsl:with-param name="pRemains" select="$pRemains"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                                        [descendant-or-self::node()
                                           [not(self::separator)]
                                           [count(following::separator)
                                            = $pRemains]
                                        ][1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pRemains" select="$pRemains"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::separator|node()[last()]">
            <xsl:variable name="vRemains" select="last()-position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vCurrent">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                         select="node()[descendant::node()
                                          [not(self::separator)]
                                          [count(following::separator)
                                           = $vRemains]
                                       ][1]">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pRemains" select="$vRemains"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="self::separator"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="separator"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Mostly a fine grained traversal. A floor hierarchy rule (in this case root element) copying itself and separator (dummy node for last group without following separator) passing remainder separators to process first child with enough following separators to process. A modified fine grained traversal identity rule, copying itself and again processing first child and following sibling with enough following separators to process. At last, a separator rule breaking the process.

**Edit 3**: Other more general solution, now with recursive identity rule

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kNodeByFolSep" match="node()[not(self::separator)]"
          use="generate-id((descendant::separator|following::separator)[1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:param name="pGroup"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
               select="node()[descendant-or-self::node()[count(.|$pGroup)
                                                         = count($pGroup)]]|@*">
                <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="$pGroup"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::separator|node()[last()]">
            <xsl:variable name="vGroup"
                 select="key('kNodeByFolSep',generate-id(self::separator))"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vCurrent">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="$vGroup"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="self::separator"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="separator"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit 4**: Now just the same as before but with key test instead of node set intersection.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kNodeByFolSep" match="node()[not(self::separator)]"
          use="concat(generate-id(),'+',
                      generate-id((descendant::separator|
                                   following::separator)[1]))"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:param name="pSeparator"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
               select="@*|node()[descendant-or-self::node()
                                    [key('kNodeByFolSep',
                                         concat(generate-id(),
                                                '+',
                                                $pSeparator))]]">
                <xsl:with-param name="pSeparator" select="$pSeparator"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::separator|node()[last()]">
            <xsl:variable name="vSeparator"
                          select="generate-id(self::separator)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vCurrent">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pSeparator" select="$vSeparator"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="self::separator"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="separator"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks! I have enjoyed answering this question. But I couldn't finish a linear complexity algorithm for the general problem... I was thinking in a fine grained traversal with foward and backward mode.

Comment: +1 for sharing the different phases of abstraction, it made it easier to understand it. The last one lies closest to what I imagined.

Comment: @Adam Schmideg: Thanks! Your question was really good. Also, I'm adding one last example ussing the identity transformation pattern but only with keys test instead of node set intersection.

Answer (score 4):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="C"
         use="generate-id(preceding::separator[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/separator"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="separator" name="commonSep">
  <separator/>
  <xsl:call-template name="genAncestors">
   <xsl:with-param name="pAncs" select="ancestor::*"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pLeaves"
        select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="separator[not(preceding::separator)]">
  <xsl:call-template name="genAncestors">
   <xsl:with-param name="pAncs" select="ancestor::*"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pLeaves"
        select="key('kFollowing', '')"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:call-template name="commonSep"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="genAncestors">
   <xsl:param name="pAncs" select="ancestor::*"/>
   <xsl:param name="pLeaves" select="."/>

   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($pAncs[2])">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$pLeaves" mode="gen"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:for-each select="$pAncs[1]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="genAncestors">
               <xsl:with-param name="pAncs" select="$pAncs[position()>1]"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pLeaves" select="$pLeaves"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="C" mode="gen">
  <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="..">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|$vCur"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C id='1'/>
    <separator/>
    <C id='2'/>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C id='3'/>
    <separator/>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C id='4'/>
  </B>
</A>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<A>
   <B>
      <C id="1"/>
   </B>
</A>
<separator/>
<A>
   <B>
      <C id="2"/>
   </B>
   <B>
      <C id="3"/>
   </B>
</A>
<separator/>
<A>
   <B>
      <C id="4"/>
   </B>
</A>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but from the question, I suspect `separator` nodes could appear at any depth; this solution is dependent on them being child nodes of `B` elements, two levels deep. Is there a more generalised way of doing this?

Comment: @Flynn1179: Just replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/separator"/>` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="//separator"/>` . The only assumption is that the `separator` elements should all be at the same depth. As usuall, I answer the specific question -- the OP or whoever else can ask a new, more generic question -- and they *do* have to provide a good example.
`

Comment: Fair enough, I tend to consider problems in more general terms, to maximise the usefulness to other interested readers, and also because a small example quite often doesn't capture the entire range of possibilities. That's my approach however, and sometimes it makes a solution more complex than it needs to be. Anyway, changing that select clause isn't enough; your 'kFollowing' key looks specifically for `C` elements.

Comment: +1 to make me think hard to understand your elegant "bottom up" approach